# Adding a rule to a theorem environment

Tags: theorems, rules, newtheorem

I have a document full of examples that I created with a simple theorem. The problem now is that I try to modify the examples' appearance by adding rules at beginning and end. This turned to be harder than I thought, but I managed to do some progress. This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{FirstExample}{First example}


\newtheorem{SecondExampleImpl}{Second example}

\newtheorem{SecondExample}{}

\renewenvironment{SecondExample}[1]{
\par\nobreak\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{3pt}\par\addvspace{12pt}
\begin{SecondExampleImpl}{{#1}}}{\end{SecondExampleImpl}\par\nobreak\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\par\addvspace{12pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{FirstExample}[First example] \label{ex:first}
This is a first example...  
\end{FirstExample}

\lipsum[1]

Ref to first example~\ref{ex:first}.


\begin{SecondExample}[Second example] \label{ex:second}
This is a second example... 
\end{SecondExample}


\lipsum[1]

Ref to second example~\ref{ex:second}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

So there are 2 theorems defining the examples. The theorem `FirstExample` is the old one, and theorem `SecondExample` is the new one. At first sight it looks like the new theorem is doing its work, but actually you can notice that the theorem title is not written properly. It is as if the argument doesn't get passed to the other macro in the right way. Also, I'm not sure whether referencing the new macro will always be correct, although in this MWE it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Do not pass the  argument to the new environment.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{FirstExample}{First example}    

\newtheorem{SecondExampleImpl}{Second example}

\newtheorem{SecondExample}{}

\renewenvironment{SecondExample} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<
{\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{3pt}\par\addvspace{12pt}\begin{SecondExampleImpl}}
{\end{SecondExampleImpl}\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\par\addvspace{12pt}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{FirstExample}[First example A] \label{ex:first}
        This is a first example...  
    \end{FirstExample}
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
    Ref to first example~\ref{ex:first}.
    
    
    \begin{SecondExample}[Second example B] \label{ex:second}
        This is a second example... 
    \end{SecondExample}
    
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
    Ref to second example~\ref{ex:second}.
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Do you happen to know how to reduce the space between the top rule and the title? I tried removing the `addvspace{12pt}` to no avail and I don't think I have to use `\vspace{-1em}` or something similar, do I?

Comment: @aaragon Try `\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{3pt}\\[-2em]\begin{SecondExampleImpl}`

Comment: Well the `\vspace{1em}` also does the trick, but now the problem is that I see the ruler and the title of the example not always stick together, sometimes they're split into different pages and that makes no sense. I didn't expect this to be this hard. Someone seems to have addressed this issue [in this post](https://comp.text.tex.narkive.com/nlUAxRyK/how-to-avoid-pagebreak-at-begin-of-new-environment) but when I use the `ntheorem` package all sort of conflicts arise.

Comment: Won’t the mininpage solution turn the environment into a float? These examples sometime span over several pages, I don’t think that’s the right solution, or am I missing something?

Comment: As I had expected hell broke loose with the minipage. Now I get the error `./book.tex:98: LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.` since I can't have figures in examples...